# Автоматический ответ в скрипте bash

Tags: linux, bash

Выполняю команду в скрипте, например svn. Иногда для продолжения работы команды требуется согласиться с чем-нибудь, т.е. через некоторое время после запуска ответить yes. Как этого добиться в срипте?

Comment: Обычно у программ, рассчитанных на скриптование, есть режим работы без запроса подтверждения.

Comment: Какая именно программа хочет у вас запросить подтверждение? svn-клиент?

Comment: Например, у [`svn`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html) есть ключ `--non-interactive`

Comment: --non-interactive не помог, т.к. вместо yes просит пароль, хотя я передаю логи и пароль

Comment: А вы уверены, что пароль приходит правильно? Проверьте, что именно вызывается. (Например, временно подмените вызов svn на вызов своей утилиты, которая логирует командную строку.)

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что svn хочет читать пароль именно из /dev/tty (а не из stdio)

Comment: с svn помогло следующее: в файле  /home/YOUR_LOGIN/.subversion/servers заменил store-passwords = no на yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте добавить перед вызовом `svn ...` вызов `yes` и конвейер (*pipe*) `|`, чтобы в итоге строка выглядела примерно так:

```
yes | svn ...
```

это если «символом согласия» должен быть `y`. если должна быть какая-то иная строка, укажите её параметром для программы `yes`.

например, если `svn`-у требуется символ `Y`, то строка должна выглядеть так:

```
yes Y | svn ...
```

а если слово `yesss`, то так:

```
yes yesss | svn ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Существует утилита [yes](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)). Перенаправляя ее вывод как раз можно добиться такого результата